# linux machine using on docker for windows

Tags: linux, docker, boot2docker, windows-server-2016

I have windows server 2016 which has docker in built into it... so I am able to create windows image based containers and play around with them.

But now I want to create run linux based images, not able to do that... get below error

```
PS C:\Users\harishr> docker pull hello-world
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
image operating system "linux" cannot be used on this platform
```

I did installed `docker-machine` to create linux machine, but not getting command line options to do that